# How to get the straight vertical line next to derivatives?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, physics

I am trying to get this to display:

[image]

My current attempt is :

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
\frac{\dd{x_c^{*}(t,u)}}{\dd{u}}=\gamma + \alpha \lambda \{[r(t)-x(t,0)]\\
+ \frac{1}{1+\alpha\beta\lambda}[\frac{\dd{r(t)}}{\dd{t}}-\gamma]
\end{align}
\end{equation}
```

I have defined a macro `\dd` above as (*uses the `physics` package*) :

```
\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}
```

I couldn't find how to display that vertical line next to the derivative ( *just left of the = sign* ) with `u=0` on it. Everything else displays fine with my code.

Comment: A compilable example would be nice

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done.

Comment: Well, the equation stuff is still only a fragment ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a fake `\mleft.` and `\mright\vert` mathematical delimiter pair.

There might be better ways.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
 \mleft.\dfrac{\dd{x_c^{*}(t,u)}}{\dd{u}}\mright\vert_{u=0} &= \gamma + \alpha \lambda \mleft\{\mleft[r(t)-x(t,0)\mright] + \frac{1}{1+\alpha\beta\lambda}
\mleft[\frac{\dd{r(t)}}{\dd{t}}-\gamma\mright]\mright\}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No comments: I will update with a better way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I should present a better solution. You can use

```
\bigg|
```

in the `amsmath` package to create the vertical line.